# Why getting lists without brackets?

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I have webscraped a URL and I am supposed to get all the links in a web page. I am using Beautiful Soup for this.

```
from bottle import route, run
import urllib2
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlparse


import json
import sys
import csv
import re

@route('/hello')
def hello():

    text=list();
    link=list();

    req = urllib2.Request("http://www.amazon.com",
                  headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
    html=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    last_page = soup.find('div', id="nav_subcats")
    for elm in last_page.findAll('a'):
        texts = elm.text
        links = elm.get('href')
        links = links.partition("&node=")[2]
        text.append(texts)
        link.append(links)

    alltext=[]
    for i,j in zip(text,link):
        alltext.append({"name":i,"id":j})
    return alltext

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

But when it returns `text`, I am getting it as `AAABBBCCCDDD`, where `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, and `DDD` are different items. Why am I not getting it in brackets like this?

```
["AAA", "BBB" "CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF"]
```

Comment: Where do return `text` to? What does the caller do with the result?

Comment: @LutzHorn i am returning it on to a browser.I am implementing it as a webservice

Comment: If you you return it to the browser, what is the `Content-Type` of the response?

Comment: Why don't you try returning it in a JSON format? The bracket notation is made by python to display a list object in memory. In memory its still a contiguous block.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Provide text and link content.